# Writing the results of a FOR XML query to a file with C#.NET

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2005, .net-3.5, for-xml

I'm trying to write the result of a FOR XML PATH query to a file. I can generate the file, but it doesn't contain the results of the query. Any one know where i'm going wrong?

```
private static void GetChartData(string OC_Ttl1, string OC_Ttl2, string OC_OL31)
    {

        //Prepare Connection Variables
        SqlConnection conn_Org = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd_Org = new SqlCommand();



        //Open Connection
        conn_Org.ConnectionString = Set_OrgChartConn();
        conn_Org.Open();

        //Execute Procedure
        cmd_Org.Connection = conn_Org;
        cmd_Org.CommandText = "dbo.usp_CreateOrgDataSet";
        cmd_Org.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd_Org.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OC_Ttl_1", OC_Ttl1);
        cmd_Org.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OC_Ttl_2", OC_Ttl2);
        cmd_Org.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OC_OL3_1", OC_OL31);




        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
        myDataSet.ReadXml(cmd_Org.ExecuteXmlReader(), XmlReadMode.Fragment);
        myDataSet.WriteXml("myData.xml");

        conn_Org.Close();






    }
```

THis is the contents of the xml file that is generated with the above code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
myDataSet.ReadXml(cmd_Org.ExecuteXmlReader(), XmlReadMode.Auto);
```

Comment: Magic. Thank you. Apologies for the late response - i've been on Holiday

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you call the stored procedure from sql management studio? Are you definitely getting the xml back?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Andrew Hare fixed my problem. Apologies for the late response - i've been on Holiday